# MySQL Rolling Value - subquery with joined value

Tags: mysql, sql, data-analysis

I am trying to do a single query over a period of a month. This is a working query:

```
SELECT AVG(days)
FROM (SELECT datediff(IF(MIN(date_end) = '0000-00-00', DATE(NOW()), MAX(date_end)), MIN(date_start)) AS days
      FROM tenancies
      WHERE deleted_at IS NULL AND date_start < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
      GROUP BY tenancies.tenant_id)
```

I want to replace `NOW()` with a date.

I have another query:

```
SELECT calendar_date
FROM calendar_dates
WHERE calendar_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND NOW()
```

This gets me all the dates I want. If I try to do a double-subquery it doesn't recognize the `calendar_date`:

```
SELECT calendar_date, (SELECT AVG(days)
FROM (SELECT datediff(IF(MIN(date_end) = '0000-00-00', DATE(calendar_date), MAX(date_end)), MIN(date_start)) AS days
      FROM tenancies
      WHERE deleted_at IS NULL AND date_start < DATE_SUB(calendar_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
      GROUP BY tenancies.tenant_id) d) AS days
FROM calendar_dates
WHERE calendar_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND NOW()
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I think adding your table schema would clarify your question, your query is wired i think you need to rewrite it in completely different way! In fact I think you need to join tables in different ways based on the position of field and the foreign key of calendar_dates and tenancies

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -1):

I assume it does not recognize `DATE(calendar_date)` and `DATE_SUB(calendar_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`, If right, Your `tenancies` table should have a calendar_date field in itself, otherwise you need to join `tenancies` with `calendar_dates` table in the middle query too. Because thats a separate query.